# Jersey 2 + Spring: @Autowired is null

Tags: java, spring, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to use Jersey 2 with Spring with help of this article:
[How to use Jersey 2 with Spring IoC container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627409/how-to-use-jersey-2-with-spring-ioc-container)

But autowired bean is null when the application tries to call it after the client request.
In applicationContext.xml i have only **component-scan** setting.

```
In pom.xml: 
<spring.version>4.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
<jersey.version>2.12</jersey.version>

@Component
@RequestScoped
@Path("/user")
public class UserREST {
    @Autowired
    private UserFacade userFacade;

    @POST
    @Path("/auth")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public AuthResponse authorize(User user){
        return userFacade.authorize(user);  // Null is caught here
    }
}
```

-

```
@Component
public class UserFacade {

    public AuthResponse authorize(com.pushock.model.User user){
        AuthResponse response = new AuthResponse();
        response.setAuthorized(true);
        return response;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPD:**
Here is my pom.xml https://bitbucket.org/spukhov/memo-ws/src/00724e00e3aa786f62fd0e43fe0606de6ae569df/pom.xml?at=master

Comment: are you scanning the correct packages with `component-scan`?

Comment: @yate component-scan is set correctly to the root package (always worked for me)

Comment: @luiggi This is not a duplicate. Please prove or leave a feedback.

Comment: Post the configurations you've done and other relevant info to replicate this problem.

Comment: Yeah, the Jersey version listed in that POM is **1.18**.

Comment: @chrylis that's for client, it shouldn't affect the server side operations.

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment (I removed it). Actual pom file is added in the question body in UPD section.

Comment: I don't know why it was marked as an 'off-topic'. But it can be considered as 'unclear what you're asking', because question does not have good background of the problem.

Comment: @JamaJurayevich Because "off-topic" includes not enough information to resolve the issue in the question, and it is (was) missing control and integration code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Spring managed beans cannot be injected to JAX-RS classes directly, you need to use Jersey extension for integrating it with Spring.

There is a maven dependency which you don't have in your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
    <version>2.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Refer to Jersey Documentation: [Chapter 22. Spring DI](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/spring.html) and at the bottom of the page, there is a link to [sample spring integration](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/2.12/examples/helloworld-spring-webapp) Github project.

Another problem I've seen in your project is you didn't show how spring context should be loaded and configured. You need to configure it in your web.xml

```
   <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Answer (score 1):

and in case you are using java based approach for spring configuration, you also need to :

```
servletContext.setInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", "<NONE>");
```

in your `WebApplicationInitializer` implementation